# In PHP , How to convert JSON into highchart supported format

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, highcharts

So basically I am stuck over a problem where I have an array in the format given below. I want to create a highcharts line chart using this data.

Everything works well, just that I am unable to convert this JSON into a highcharts recognized JSON.

```
{
    name: [
        1000,
        1001
    ],
    data: [
        {
            January: "7",
            February: "4",
            March: "1",
            April: "0",
            May: "0",
            June: "1",
            July: "3",
            August: "6",
            September: "2",
            October: "2",
            November: "8",
            December: "7"
        },
        {
            January: "6",
            February: "10",
            March: "1",
            April: "1",
            May: "0",
            June: "0",
            July: "0",
            August: "2",
            September: "3",
            October: "2",
            November: "2",
            December: "5"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Highcharts supported JSON**

I want to convert this array into the structure like :

```
[
      {
         name: '1000',
         data: [7,4,1,0,0,1,3,6,2,2,8,7]
     }, {
         name: '1001',
         data: [6,10,1,1,0,0,0,2,3,2, 2,5]
     }
]
```

Comment: Please show your current PHP code

Comment: Your second structure isn't valid JSON. You can't have `{` after `{`. Are you sure you want the `{` on the first line?

Comment: It should probably be `[ { name: '1000', data: [...] }, { name: '1001', data: [...] } ]`

Comment: you are right @Barmar , it was a typo

Comment: can you give an example ? @kamlesh.bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `foreach` to loop through one of the properties, and build an associative array using that element and the values from the corresponding element in the other property.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($input['name'] as $i => $name) {
    $result[] = array('name' => $name, 'data' => array_map('intval', array_values($input['data'][$i])));
}
```

Comment: how can i remove the quotes from the data array for integers

Comment: {
name: 1000,
data: [
"7",
"4",
"1",
"0",
"0",
"1",
"3",
"6",
"2",
"2",
"8",
"7"
]
},

Comment: Use `array_map('intval', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  

$json_res = json_decode('{
    "name": [
        1000,
        1001
    ],
    "data": [
        {
            "January": "7",
            "February": "4",
            "March": "1",
            "April": "0",
            "May": "0",
            "June": "1",
            "July": "3",
            "August": "6",
            "September": "2",
            "October": "2",
            "November": "8",
            "December": "7"
        },
        {
            "January" :"6",
            "February" :"10",
            "March" :"1",
            "April" :"1",
            "May" :"0",
            "June" :"0",
            "July" :"0",
            "August" :"2",
            "September" :"3",
            "October" :"2",
            "November" :"2",
            "December" :"5"
        }
    ]
}',true);  

$result = array();
foreach ($json_res['name'] as $key => $val) {

    $result[] = array('name' => $val, 'data' => array_values($json_res['data'][$key]));

}

echo json_encode($result);exit;
#echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); 
# answer the way you want
//[{"name":1000,"data":["7","4","1","0","0","1","3","6","2","2","8","7"]},{"name":1001,"data":["6","10","1","1","0","0","0","2","3","2","2","5"]}]
?>
```